# The second conjecture about the degrees of special polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, polynomials, prime-numbers

Define the congruence "modulo m" on exponential Taylor series following the previous post ([A conjecture about the degrees of special polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265227/a-conjecture-about-the-degrees-of-special-polynomials))

It has been conjectured, that if we define the sequence of polynomials $Q_{n,k}(x)$:
$$
Q_{n,k}(x):= \left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+...+\frac{x^{p_n-1}}{p_n-1}\right)^k \mod p_n!
$$
then $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, 2<k<p_{n-1}:$
$$
\boxed{\deg Q_{n,k}(x)=k\cdot p_{n-1}}
$$
(where $p_n$ is the n-th prime number and so $p_{n-1}$ is the previous one)

It is also conjectured to be true for $k=2$ and all $n\neq 1,2,5~(p_n\neq 2,3,11)$.

I still have no idea, why the degrees of polynomials of this kind have such "number theoretical" properties and would appreciate, if you could give a proof of this fact, maybe share philosophical speculations about the nature of this structure or post some references. Thank you.

Comment: I think you meant to say: $\deg Q_{n,k}(x)=k\cdot(p_n-1)$ instead of $\deg Q_{n,k}(x)=k\cdot p_{n-1}$. Right?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan No, the calculations show that the degree is $k\cdot p_{n-1}$. It is $p_{n}-1$ only for $k=1$.